# OpenModelica: No output variables or solution file

Tags: linux, openmodelica

So I am a newbie to OpenModelica.  I have a bit of experience using LMS Amesim.  I created my first simple model using OM and simulated it from within the OMeditor.

[image]

When I switch to the plot window, there are NO output variables to plot.  That tells me that the simulation may not have run.  However, no error messages popped up.  When I checked the model, I found it to be fine (not overconstrained or underconstrained).

[image]

**What gives?  This is OM 1.14 on Linux Ubuntu 16.04.**

My Modelica file is a simple 2nd order system with feedback control is available via [pastebin here](https://www.pastiebin.com/5c142ca37ae4b) or may be downloaded here via [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y-yKQiXOO8kL2KPYhil5CtvvIBFcjj9y)

The messages that I have from the output window are:

> /tmp/OpenModelica_drN/OMEdit/Feedback/Feedback -port=35318 -logFormat=xmltcp -override=startTime=0,stopTime=100,stepSize=0.2,tolerance=1e-6,solver=dassl,outputFormat=csv,variableFilter=.* -r=/tmp/OpenModelica_drN/OMEdit/Feedback/Feedback_res.csv -w -lv=LOG_STATS -inputPath=/tmp/OpenModelica_drN/OMEdit/Feedback -outputPath=/tmp/OpenModelica_drN/OMEdit/Feedback
>
> The initialization finished successfully without homotopy method.
>   The simulation finished successfully.

Comment: What do you have inside file: /tmp/OpenModelica_drN/OMEdit/Feedback/Feedback_res.csv? Is there any data?

Comment: Could you also give the actual model, not the flattened version of it so I can test with it on my Linux box?

Comment: @AdrianPop Indeed! You are correct... the /tmp folder had the CSV.  It would be useful to actually have plotting capabilities from within OM though.  Here is the [model file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y-yKQiXOO8kL2KPYhil5CtvvIBFcjj9y) via google drive.  Also updated in Q.

Comment: It should actually work automatically after simulation, the plotting should be opened up and all the variables should be there. I will check with your model.

Comment: Just checked with your model, for me the plot opens automatically after simulation with the results.

Comment: Strange... can you share your OM configuration file?

Comment: Can you go to: Tools->OpenModelica Compiler CLI and copy all the stuff there and put it someplace. Alternatively you can put the file /tmp/OpenModelica_drN/OMEdit/omeditcommunication.log someplace and give me the link.

Comment: Here is my ~/.config/openmodelica/omedit.ini https://pastebin.com/P2bEWvX7

Comment: Here is my [omeditcommunication LOG](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tUePVjBJLUCzZ8rWL2TPRsYM2KkpNjDi/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks, but i need it after you simulate the Feedback model. I have this in my log which reads the results: https://pastebin.com/5eMtm6iq

Comment: Here is the "compiler CLI" stuff as a [gdrive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CV1R99bOS6-K7PO0qvsZQMjpBi2wGIl7/view?usp=sharing).  This is AFTER solving.

Comment: Ok. That is strange, is doesn't read the result after the simulation. Maybe you have some strange OMEdit settings. Just close OMEdit rename ~/.config/openmodelica/omedit.ini to something else,  restart OMEdit and resimulate Feedback.

Comment: After closing OM, renaming the omedit.ini to a different name, restarting and running No luck `:(` Still no variables in plot window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185279/discussion-between-adrian-pop-and-drn).

Comment: I opened a bug report about it and we'll fix it.
https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug. Should be fixed now:
https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5251

Comment: Oh, thank you.  Should I be reinstalling OpenModelica 1.14 now?

Comment: I guess just apt update and apt upgrade should do it.

Comment: Works perfectly well now!